# rails radio_button configuration with one to one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Products which can be free, paied or private... I have designed that with a second Table called product_details. There is a many to one relation from products to product_details. To let the user choose what kind of product he wants to create, I want to use list of 3 radio_buttons where he can choose from. I tied to do it with that code, but with no luck:

```
<% ProductDetails.all.each do |product_detail| %>
    <%= f.radio_button @product, "product_detail", product_detail %>
    <%= product_detail.name.humanize %>
<% end %>
```

The following error shows up.. hat is the problem here?

```
undefined method `merge' for #<Products id: 1, name: "free", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.radio_button :product, "product_detail", product_detail.name %>
```

Comment: no gives me the same error... could it be that there is a problem to compare objects and not strings in "product_detail", product_detail?